# General WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

Am just creating myself a WPF application, like outlook. am having all forms seperately. I just want one main window and and am haivng navigation pane in left side. when ever i click items in pane, i just want to load corresponding form to the main window in right container. How i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a design pattern like [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter) or [MVVM.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Also you probably want to use the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) which will benefit the maintainability of your UI related commands.

### Tutorials:

**WPF Patterns**

[This tutorial](http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-model-view-presenter) should get you started with these patterns. Paul Stovell shows how to implement MVP and MVVM and displays strenghts and weaknesses of each pattern.

**OutlookBar:**

[This link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFOutlookBar.aspx) should get you started with the UI part of your challenge. It shows how to use such a control and implement the Command pattern.

HTH

Comment: @ Stephane Thanks, ya i look that paul MVVM article, i cant understand that mvvm pattern. they are not using forms. Is there anyother simpler way?

Comment: You should try to find a sample project and use it as a starting point like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MVVMForDummies.aspx 

It has some learning curve to use these, but it is really worth it at the end.
ps: When you say forms, are you referring to xaml views?

Comment: Yes Stephane.. forms i meant here is xaml form views. i will start learn now itself. thanks. if you got any things regarding this mean send me.